# Calculate Button dimensions by its caption (text) without creating it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

If I know the text for a `Button`, is there any way to calculate the button dimensions (width and height) before creating the button?

Buttons have the same chrome, paddings, margins, and font. They just vary system by system. So, in theory, button dimensions can be determined by its text.

In case you wonder why I would want to do that, I want to create a dynamic array of horizontal buttons, and if there is not enough space I would to create a menu instead of the excess buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Button button = new Button(context);
button.setText("Testing");
button.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int width = button.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = button.getMeasuredHeight();
```

As far as I know, if you are creating it from java, it'll give you proper values always.

Comment: I wish I could do it without creating a `Button`, and just by calculating system UI metrics and measuring the text, to avoid unnecessary creation of object(s). But if that is not possible or very difficult, I think this is a quick and easy solution. Come to think of it, probably creating an invisible button would have little impact on performance. Thank you.

Comment: Theoretically we can calculate without creating `Button` too. But for this we need `Paint` object with same `Typeface`, `Font Size` & other UI settings to measure exact space occupied by text & exact values for `paddings` and `margins`. Because **buttons do have paddings in default style** so measuring only text with `Paint` will not give right values. But as you said, creating buttons may have a slight impact on performance taking some extra memory (depends on how many times you are calculating) still I believe it's easier way though.